# Iron-Router Wait-On Doesn't wait on yields

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have noticed that my router definition does not wait on the subscriptions to finish for the yieldTemplates, but does wait for the main template. Is there a way to have the yield templates also wait on the `waitOn`?

Route:

```
Router.route('/', {
 template : 'main',
 layoutTemplate: 'appLayout',
 waitOn: function () {
    // return one handle, a function, or an array
    return [Meteor.subscribe('userInformation'), Meteor.subscribe('projects')];
 },
 data: function () {
    return Meteor.user();
 },
 action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
        this.render();
    } else {
        this.render('login');
    }
 },
 yieldTemplates: {
    'dash': {to: 'side'}
 }
});
```

I am using the data attribute in my dash template and initially it returns undefined. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that syntax is deprecated, the docs use this syntax to define yield templates:

```
this.render('dash', {to: 'side'});
```

Never had a `waitOn` issue using this syntax, give it a go?

Comment: Which version of iron:router deprecates 'this syntax'. We're currently up to `1.0.12`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `yieldTemplates` in the router, try rendering content into the layout regions from the main template using the `contentFor` template/helper.

First remove `yieldTemplates` from `Router.route`.  Then, add a `{{> contentFor}}` template in your main template:

```
<template name="main">
    {{> contentFor region="side" template="dash"}}
</template>
```

Alternatively, you can use the helper version of `contentFor`:

```
<template name="main">
    {{#contentFor 'side'}}
        {{> dash}}
        <!-- and anything else you want to include -->
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

Here is a MeteorPad that demonstrates that this works:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/QCo3JsFLr6R438izF/Leaderboard

More on `contentFor` can be found in the iron-router docs:

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-into-regions-using-contentfor.

Also, `yieldTemplates` has now been replaced by `yieldRegions` in more recent versions of Iron-Router (I'm using 1.0.7), but templates specified here still do not wait for the `waitOn()` function.